# Django set creator/owner for the object when created

Tags: django, django-models, auto-populate

Let's say I have a simple model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

I would like to set owner (request.user, logged in user) for the object automatically when it is created. I've searched a lot of different options but most of them are related to how you do it in admin side and other ones just don't work for me. I tried this for example http://blog.jvc26.org/2011/07/09/django-automatically-populate-request-user and then I've tried many ways to override save method or some kind of pre_save signal stuff. Nothing seems to do the trick, I just get an error

```
IntegrityError at /new
null value in column "owner_id" violates not-null constraint
```

What is the right way to do that? I know that this is simple think to do but I just can't find the way to do it.

...EDIT...
My create view looks like this:

```
class CreateContactView(LoginRequiredMixin, ContactOwnerMixin, CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = models.Contact
    template_name = 'contacts/edit_contact.html'
    form_class = forms.ContactForm
    inlines = [forms.ContactAddressFormSet]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.owner = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('contacts-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateContactView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('contacts-new')
        return context
```

That is just one way I tried to solve that problem so far. I found that solution from http://blog.jvc26.org/2011/07/09/django-automatically-populate-request-user

Comment: Where is the code that produced the error?

Comment: @m5seppal show the view code where you save the model

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using class based views, I edited the question

Comment: I manged to get this work when I changed my view to use django's generic CreateView instead of CreateWithInlinesView. I posted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155302/django-integrityerror-at-new-null-value-in-column-owner-id-violates-not-null) about that problem. Thank you guys from your help!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using `ContactForm` `ModelForm`:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact = form.save(commit=False)
            contact.owner = request.user
            contact.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
         # do stuff
```

Comment: Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

please post the exact code of what you tried.

If your view requires that a user is logged in, make sure it is enforced.  This can be done by using the `@login_required` decorator

If you are in a view, and using a `ModelForm` to create the `Contact`, pass the `commit=False` kwarg to save method (like the example in the link you posted).  This will keep the contact from being created until you assign the `owner = request.user`.

Since a logged in user is only available within the context of a request, just make sure that you are setting `owner` attribute it the views when creating a new `Contact`

Comment: That's exactly what I've tried but I still get that error: null value in column "owner_id" violates not-null constraint

It looks like form_valid is never called. Do you have any idea what I should do for that?

Comment: @well also make sure that request has a user. You could do this with the `@login_required` decorator.  I'm assuming the user is not logged in that's why `request.user` is `None`

Comment: I'm using that LoginRequiredMixin, it should do the same thing. It's from the django-braces.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default implementation of the `form_valid` method sets `self.object`, which is then used by `get_success_url` to determine where to redirect to.

If you replace your local `obj` variable with `self.object`, you should be fine:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.owner = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

I find a quick check of the original implementation for side-effects on the [Classy Class-Based Views](http://ccbv.co.uk/) Web site, or the [Django source-code on GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/views/generic) useful for spotting any side effects I need to reproduce in a subclass implementation.

Comment: Nothing Happened.